# How to find all the products with specific multi attribute values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using postgresql.

I have a table called custom_field_answers. The data looks like this

```
Id | product_id | value      | number_value | 
4  | 2          |            | 117          |
3  | 1          |            | 107          |
2  | 1          | bangle     |              |
1  | 2          | necklace   |              |
```

I want to find all the products which has text_value as 'bangle' and number_value less than 50.

Here was my first attempt.

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "custom_field_answers" 
ON "custom_field_answers"."product_id" = "products"."id" 
WHERE ("custom_field_answers"."value" ILIKE 'bangle')
```

Here is my second attempt.

```
 SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "custom_field_answers" 
ON "custom_field_answers"."product_id" = "products"."id" 
where ("custom_field_answers"."number_value" < 50)
```

Here is my final attempt.

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "custom_field_answers" 
ON "custom_field_answers"."product_id" = "products"."id" 
WHERE ("custom_field_answers"."value" ILIKE 'bangle') 
AND ("custom_field_answers"."number_value" < 50)
```

but this does not select any product record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WHERE clause can only look at columns from one row at a time.

So if you need a condition that applies to two *different* rows from a table, you need to join to that table twice, so you can get columns from both rows.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM "products" AS p
INNER JOIN "custom_field_answers" AS a1 ON p."id" = a1."product_id"
INNER JOIN "custom_field_answers" AS a2 ON p."id" = a1."product_id" 
WHERE a1."value" = 'bangle' AND a2."number_value" < 50
```

Answer (score 1):

It produces no records because there is no `custom_field_answers` record that meets both criteria. What you want is a list of `product_id`s that have the necessary records in the table. Just in case no one gets to writing the SQL for you, and until I have a chance to work it out myself, I thought I would at least explain to you why your query is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

SELECT p.* FROM products LEFT JOIN custom_field_answers c
ON (c.product_id = p.id AND c.value LIKE '%bangle%' AND c.number_value

Hope it helps

Comment: I don't believe that will work. Each resulting row in the `JOIN` will **EITHER** have the `value` field or the `number_value` field, but not both. You could JOIN the custom table to itself and then find matches.

Answer (score 0):

Your bangle-related number_value fields are null, so you won't be able to do a straight comparison in those cases.  Instead, convert your nulls to 0s first.

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "custom_field_answers" 
ON "custom_field_answers"."product_id" = "products"."id" 
WHERE ("custom_field_answers"."value" LIKE '%bangle%') 
AND (coalesce("custom_field_answers"."number_value", 0) < 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't actually test it, but this general idea should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM custom_field_answers
        WHERE
            custom_field_answers.product_id = products.id
            AND value = 'bangle'
    )
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM custom_field_answers
        WHERE
            custom_field_answers.product_id = products.id
            AND number_value < 5
    )
```

In plain English: Get all products such that...

- there is a related row in `custom_field_answers` where `value = 'bangle'`
- and there is (possibly different) related row in  `custom_field_answers` where `number_value < 5`.