# Shopping cart - multiple attribute values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following tables for the products and shopping cart:

// PRODUCT TABLES

```
Products:

    id  | Product_value
    -----------------------
    1   | Product 1


Attributes:

    id  | Attribute_value
        -----------------
    1   | Color
    2   | Size


Attribute_values:

    id  | Attribute_id  | Value_value
    ---------------------------------
    1   | 1             | Black
    2   | 1             | Red
    3   | 1             | Blue
    4   | 2             | S
    5   | 2             | M
    6   | 2             | L
    7   | 2             | XL

Product_attribute_values

    Product_id  | Attribute_id  | Value_id
    --------------------------------------
    1           | 1             | 1
    1           | 1             | 2
    1           | 1             | 3
    1           | 2             | 4
    1           | 2             | 5
    1           | 2             | 6
    1           | 2             | 7
```

// DB TABLES

```
Cart:

    id  | product_id    | number_value
    ----------------------------------
    1   | 1             | 1
    2   | 1             | 1

Product_attribute_value:

    Cart_id     | attribute_id  | value_id
    --------------------------------------
    1           | 1             | 1
    1           | 2             | 4
    2           | 1             | 2
    2           | 2             | 5
```

So:

- Customer wants product 1 in black size S
- Customer wants product 1 in red size M

A product can contain multiple attributes values.

By adding a product in cart with AJAX->JSON i have the following data:

```
- productid
- number
- attribute= array(     // example: color
    attribute_id
    value_id
  )
- attribute= array(     // example: size
    attribute_id
    value_id
  )
```

With which query (PDO) can i see if this combination already exists? If it exists i want to change the number of this product

At '[How to find all the products with specific multi attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235563/how-to-find-all-the-products-with-specific-multi-attribute-values)' they use EXISTS.
How do i do this with PDO and unlimited attributes (there can be more then only color and size, but not every product has attributes).

Answer (score 0):

"Classical" SQL approach will require you to do `JOIN` or `sub-query` on each attribute filter.
So if you will need to find products via 5 filters (attribute values), you will need to create a SQL-query with 5 JOINs or sub-queries. Same as in a question, you posted a link to.

Which is not scalable at all, a you may guess.

So, I would like to offer a different, but a bit "haskish" way.
You can make a query on `products_attribute_values` table and get pairs like:

`ProductID`, `How many attributes/filters this products match`

Here is a query:

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) AS `attributes_matching` FROM Product_attribute_values
WHERE 
Attribute_id1=Value1  // example: color
AND
Attribute_id2=Value2  // example: size
AND
Attribute_id3=Value3  // example: for-man/women/kid
AND 
Attribute_id4=Value4  // example: Manufacturer
AND
Attribute_id5=Value5  // example: Material
GROUP BY product_id
```

In general you can use this `attributes_matching` value as search ranking value, you can sort & filter by it. 
For example, in the example above, if there no matching to all 5 filters, you can show products which are matching 4 filters.

If you want to get products which matching ALL 5 filters (strict filtering), you can just add `HAVING` at the end of the query:

```
...
AND
Attribute_id5=Value5  // example: Material
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING attributes_matching=5   // 5 - number of filters in this case
```